# Headless chrome web driver too slow and unable to download file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, download, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to download a file using python headless chrome web driver. My code is running to slow.There is no output(downloaded) file. I am getting no error. Any help would be appreciated.
here is my code:

```
# Getting All User Credintials
for x in range(2,st.max_row + 1):
    Users.append([st.cell(x, 1).value,st.cell(x, 2).value, st.cell(x, 3).value])

# Looping through Users
for item in Users:
    try:
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        prefs = {"download.default_directory": os.getcwd()}
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

        chrome.get(Url)

        chrome.find_element_by_id("formId:codEmpresa").send_keys(item[0])  # Enterinng login Credintials
        chrome.find_element_by_id("formId:codUsuario").send_keys(item[1])
        chrome.find_element_by_id("formId:senha").send_keys(item[2])
        chrome.find_element_by_link_text("Entrar").click()  # Clicking Login button

        chrome.get("https://www3.honda.com.br/newihs/AbrirPag?Opcao=1998")
        chrome.find_element_by_name("W0002vWDINI").send_keys(DateFrom)  # Entering DateForm
        chrome.find_element_by_name("W0002vWDFIM").send_keys(DateTo)  # Entering DateTo
        chrome.find_element_by_name("W0002BT_CONFIRMAR").click()  # Clicking Confirm button
        wait = WebDriverWait(chrome, 10)
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'W0002BT_INFORMAR2')))
        chrome.find_element_by_name("W0002BT_INFORMAR2").click()  # Clicking Download button
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable the **proxy** and try, it should increase performance

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')
```

I found that it helped me.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to [iamsankalp89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8164333/iamsankalp89) answer:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')
```

**these additional options helped me to drastically increase the performance**:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'");
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
```

(Source: from this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/issues/561) and this [comment](https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/issues/561#issuecomment-373666779) in particular)

Comment: This is gold! ^_^

Comment: Thank you @teoretic. This option really speeded up the performance!!!

Answer (score 1):

This should help (C#)

```
chromeoptions.AddArguments("--headless", "--window-size=1920,1200");
```